# Control Error icon showing twice after styling

Tags: wpf, validation, styles, infragistics, errorprovider

I'm applying this style to an `infragistics` control `XamDateTimeEditor`.
The new error icon displays as expected.

issue: The original error style is still displaying when a validation error occurs. Thus making the control to have two error icon styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type XamDateTimeEditor}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border 
                        Background="Red" 
                        Width="25" 
                        Height="25" 
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        >
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="Error" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            FontWeight="Bold" 
                            Foreground="White" 
                            />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Try adding this to your Style: `<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />`

Comment: @EdPlunkett it completely changed the shape of the control. Now, I only get the new provider without the control.

Comment: I'm surprised you ever got any control at all, since you're replacing the template with an error template. What if in your setter you change Property to `Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"`, set that instead of `Template` to the template you've got in your question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I made a mistake when I copied the code over. It should have been `Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"`. Same issue.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thanks. I think it's possible that the Infragistics control template is doing its error indication in its template rather than using the conventional error template. If you go into "Design" mode in the XAML designer, you can right click on the control and select "Edit Template | Edit a Copy" from the context menu. That should give you a copy of what it's really using. Then you can look in there for a trigger on the error state, and either replace what they're doing with your ErrorTemplate, or just delete their error thing and leave your own in place.

Answer (score 0):

Using a view model that implements `IDataErrorInfo` is the best approach when customizing an error template that targets `XamDateTimeEditor`.

This was previously discussed and demonstrated on our forums at:  http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/109152.aspx

https://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.